# EditText linespacingextra not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using linespacingextra in EditText. But for some reason it isn't working.Following is the EditText

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/previousHospitilization"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:hint="Previous Hospitilization"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="20dp"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
```

I dont find any difference between the editText fields with android:lineSpacingExtra and the normal one. This is in a fragment. Is that the reason. 
Thank you.

Comment: did you fill up the EditText with some text ?

Comment: Yeah. I did fill and check it. It isn't showing any difference

Comment: please check this , there is issue with lollipop as per this page https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78706

Comment: How can this issue be resolved? Is there any workaround for this?